# how to make smooth scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using bootstrap and this is my code. how to make smooth scroll ?
Please help me

```
<div id="navbar-normal" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
        <div class="container">
            <a href="" class="navbar-brand">
                <img src="assets/images/logo.svg" alt="">
            </a>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#home" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#about" class="nav-link">About</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#news" class="nav-link">News</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#contact" class="nav-link">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<section id="home"><h1>Home</h1></section>
    <section id="about"><h1>About</h1></section>
    <section id="news"><h1>News</h1></section>
    <section id="contact"><h1>Contact</h1></section>
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**You don't need to use javascript to add smooth scrolling**

in css use this

```
:root{
  behavior: smooth;
}
```

Comment: I have no diea how this could have been checked as answer. `behavior` as property does not exsist. it is `scroll-behavior` and should be added to the `html` selector not to the root.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use javascript to add smooth scrolling, it can be done by setting `scroll-behavior: smooth;` css property.
Example:

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

However that is not supported by all browsers See [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/css-scroll-behavior)

By using a library like [`scroll-js`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scroll-js), you can get scrolling working on browsers like safari.

Comment: This is the only fully complete and correct answer that uses the correct property and selector to apply to.

Comment: @tacoshy :root is also correct, because :root matches root element, which aleays should be html. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:root

Answer (score 0):

It's not obvious what you mean. If you mean that you want the page to smoothly go from one anchor link to the next, use CSS [`scroll-behavior`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior). If you want elements on the page to move smoothly as the user scrolls with their finger or mouse wheel, I would suggest [Locomotive Scroll](https://locomotivemtl.github.io/locomotive-scroll/) or similar. However, you're probably looking for the first option.

CSS `scroll-behavior` demo:

```css
:root {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

/* demo */
nav {
  display: block;
  height: 1rem;
  position: fixed;
}
section { 
  height: 100vh; 
  padding-top: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="#a">Go to A</a>
  <a href="#b">Go to B</a>
  <a href="#c">Go to C</a>
</nav>

<section id="a">Section A</section>
<section id="b">Section B</section>
<section id="c">Section C</section>
```

Answer (score -3):

**in CSS use this**

```
:root{
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

**in JavaScript use this**

```
document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="#"]').forEach(anchor => {
            anchor.addEventListener('click', function(e){
                e.preventDefault()

                document.querySelector(this.getAttribute('href')).scrollIntoView({
                    behavior: 'smooth'
                })
            })
        })
```

Comment: You don't need JavaScript for this. It is unnecessary = increases load time and decreases performance (if only slightly) of web page. Use the CSS way instead